# Diagnosing linear skew of residuals in boosted tree

Tags: regression, cart, caret, boosting

I have trained a boosted tree regression with the following code (out of the `caret` and `gbm` packages:

```
fm <- target ~ .

bt.tune.grid <- expand.grid(
  interaction.depth = seq(3, 7, by = 2),
  n.trees = seq(500, 1000, by = 100),
  shrinkage = c(0.01, 0.1),
  n.minobsinnode = seq(6, 10, by = 2)
)

bt <- train(
  fm,
  method = "gbm",
  data = train.data,
  trControl=trainControl(method="cv",number=5), 
  tuneGrid = bt.tune.grid,
  verbose = F,
  distribution = "gaussian"
)
```

This will automatically select a model with the lowest RMSE on cross validation. When I diagnose the residuals with

`plot(bt$finalModel$fit, train.data$target-bt$finalModel$fit)`

I get very linearly skewed residuals (see below)[image: residual plot]

Any help diagnosing this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trees (and ensembles of trees) tend to under fit in the extremes. The terminal nodes usually estimates the prediction using the mean of the training set points in the terminal node. Because of this, they can't really predict the ends of the response variable very well and tend to regress to the mean.

Your plot is a bit extreme though compared to the others that I've seen.

Try using [cubist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Cubist/index.html) which does something similar to boosting and fits linear models in the terminal nodes. This may improve the situation.

Max